# Use both v4 Fragment and native Fragment in One ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library

Is there a way to use both v4 fragment and native fragment in same ViewPager? Any ideas helps.Thank you!

Comment: I do not think it is a particularly good idea to mix native and backport fragments in the same activity, let alone the same `PagerAdapter`.

Comment: The thing is that we are providing a native fragment to our customer and they want to use this native fragment in their ViewPager, in which all other fragments are v4 fragments.

Comment: Then you should be providing a v4 fragment to the customer. Or, you should exposing enough of the code that they could create their own v4 fragment based on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The framework Fragment and support library Fragment are managed by entirely different FragmentManagers, and it wouldn't be feasible to make a solution that can page through both while keeping the fragments' lifecycles intact. My suggestion would be to convert the framework Fragment to a support Fragment, which should take minimal effort.

Comment: Thank you! But the native fragment we have is a RowsFragment. Is there a easy way to convert this into a v4 Fragment? Or is there any other workarounds?

Comment: Wow, looks like there isn't a support version of RowsFragment. That's disappointing. Since Leanback is only supported on relatively new versions, the framework Fragments actually should be fine to work with. Simplest solution in this case would probably be to go with that.

Comment: However, consider that ViewPagers in a Leanback app (assuming you're using d-pad navigation) could probably be emulated perfectly by switching and animating the views manually. Then you could avoid having to use a PagerAdapter and use fragments as you please.